# How to check if keyListener is triggered by setText?

Tags: java, actionlistener, jtextfield, keylistener, settext

```
public class KeyListener extends KeyAdapter
{
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke)
    {
        try
        {

            char i = ke.getKeyChar();
            String asteriskNum = passwordJTextField.getText();
            String str = Character.toString(i);

            if(i == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE)
            {
                pswdAL.remove(pswdAL.size() - 1);
            }
```

And I have a bunch of other things.

My problem is, at the end of this keyReleased method, I set the text in the JTextField that I'm listening to. That seems to trigger it again and erase one more character in my password ArrayList.

I'm curious as to why. The line above is the ONLY place where I remove a character from the ArrayList. That must mean that when setText happens, char i is in fact  KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE. I don't know why that is. But is there a way to make sure the if statement is not triggered by the setText?

---

Update: I found a temporary fix. I overrided the keyPressed method and made a boolean wasReleased. In the keyPressed, I set it to false. In the keyReleased, I set it to true. So that it won't go through again because of the setText. It goes through ONLY if you PRESSED a key.

Comment: It should be `ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE` because `i` is the key's character not its code and why are you storing the characters in a list when you can get them all using this statement `passwordJTextField.getText()` ?

Comment: I tried it, and in my trials, `setText()` does not trigger any Key event.

Comment: @Titus I'm hiding the password as the user types it in, so the passwordJTextField would just be a bunch of asterisks.

Comment: There is a `JPasswordField` for that. Here you can find more details on how to use that https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html

Comment: @Titus Oh wow. Never knew that. Thank you!